# Does Berkeley DB only support one processor operation

Tags: python, nginx, berkeley-db

I use Berkeley DB(BDB) in nginx.  When a request arrives, nginx passes the URI as a key to BDB and checks if that key has a value in BDB file.

I actually did in an example. I add some data in BDB, and run nginx, it's OK. I can access it.
But when I add some data in running BDB with nginx (using Python), I can't get the new data.  Even I use the another python interpreter access the BDB file, it was actually has the new data.

Steps of the request in nginx:

1. start up nginx, and it will init my plugin (BDB env and init)
2. a request comes in
3. control in plugin, check if key(uri) has a value.  If true, return it, or pass
4. ...rest of process

Comment: possible duplicate of [can a berkeley database be opened and accessed from multiple programs at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749885/can-a-berkeley-database-be-opened-and-accessed-from-multiple-programs-at-the-sam)

Comment: See the related question, I updated it with correct links to the Oracle documentation, including http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/lock.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it supports

- A Single Process With One Thread
- A Single Process With Multiple Threads
- Groups of Cooperating Processes
- Groups of Unrelated Processes